# my avatar command doesn't support gif format on discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, format, discord, discord.js

```
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#985ce7")
        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setDescription(`[Avatar URL Link](${message.author.displayAvatarURL()})`)
        .setImage(message.author.displayAvatarURL())

        message.channel.send(embed)
```

if the command used by the avatar user in gif format, then the result is not in gif format.

but, I try as below

```
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#985ce7")
        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setDescription(`[Avatar URL Link](${message.author.displayAvatarURL()})`)
        .setImage(message.author.displayAvatarURL({format : "gif"}))
         message.channel.send(embed)
```

if the command used by the avatar user in png format, then the results do not appear pictures.

Thanks before!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This way your embed will support gif

```
.setImage(message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic : true}))
```